# Sorting a vector of ints that have been converted into strings

Tags: c++, string, sorting, int

So I am needing to sort a vector of strings in numerical order. I am using the `sort` [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/#cpp11) and it almost works. Say I have the numbers `10, 20, 5, 200, 50, 75` that have been converted to strings. The sort function sorts them like so: `10, 200, 25, 5, 50, 75`. So it is only sorting the first character I suppose? Is there an *easy* way to get it to sort more than the first character? And yes, they must be converted to strings for my particular use.

Thanks!

Comment: How critical is performance of your sorting algorithm?  The easy answer is to just use something like `boost::lexical_cast` to do the sorting on the underlying integer values.

Comment: It's probably doing a string comparison. Can you sort it while it's still a vector of ints?

Comment: @Chad Not very critical. This is a very, very small vector. It might hold at most 20 elements.

Comment: For 20 elements anything goes... Either convert, sort and convert, or sort converting on the fly... probably not worth developing a specialized comparator to optimize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v {"123", "453", "78", "333"};
  std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [] (std::string const &A, std::string const &B) { return std::stoi(A) < std::stoi(B);});

  for(auto i : v) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is really why you want to sort this after it became a vector of strings and not before that.

The simplest way to sort a vector of strings holding ints might be to convert it to ints, sort that and then convert back to strings into the first vector... which in your case could be more efficient if you did not convert to strings in the first place.

Regarding the suggestion to convert to `int` on the fly inside the comparator, that is going to be expensive. Comparing `int` is trivial compared with the process of conversion from `string` to `int`. Sorting is `O(N log N)` (expected) number of comparisons, if you convert on the fly you will be doing `O(N log N)` conversions, if you convert once you will do `O(N)` conversions and `O(N log N)` trivial `int` compares.

You can also handcraft an algorithm to do the comparison. If you can assume that all values are positive and there are no leading zeros, a number, represented as a string, is larger than any other number represented as a string with a shorter length. You could use that to build a comparisson function:

```
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(std::string const & lhs, std::string const & rhs) const {
        return lhs.size() < rhs.size()
            || (lhs.size() == rhs.size() && lhs < rhs);
    }
};
```

If there can be leading zeros, it is simple to find how many leading zeroes and adjust the `size` accordingly inside the comparator. If the numbers can be negative you can further extend the comparator to detect the sign and then apply something similar to the comparisson above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a standard map instead?

```
// now since map is already sorted by keys, you look up on the integer to get the equivalent string.
std::map<int, string> integersAndStrings;
integersAndStrings[1] = "one";
integersAndStrings[2] = "two";
integersAndStrings[3] = "three";
```

You could also write a variant of 40two's example.  Instead of stoi, you can just make your own predicate to compare the characters.  If lhs has fewer digits than rhs, lhs must be a smaller number (assuming no floating point); if same number of digits than compare the strings (i.e., what David Rodriguez showed you in his answer).  I didn't notice that he had already suggested that when I wrote my answer.  The only additional thing that I am adding is really the suggestion of using another container (i.e., std::map).